# Android message Sending without sending number to next user

Tags: android

I have a website through which I can send an sms to any number.

Now what I want is to develop an application in Android on which I have a "Send Sms" button and an text field. When the user presses the "Send" button I want to use that website's application and send the sms through it.

Is it possible? Because I really don't know that it is possible or not.

Alternatively:

I want to send sms from my mobile but don't want that reciever get my number. I did it in case if user is using same application but what to do if user didn't using same application.

Comment: Create an API for your website and send message through that API   http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/

Comment: shiju b... what you are suggesting is right but it will be usefull when other persone is using my app. i want a acase in which other user is not using my application..